# I have installed XDEBUG.suddenly it got removed from phpinfo and on php - m

Tags: xdebug

I have installed XDEBUG.suddenly it got removed from phpinfo and on php - m command.Now I tried re-installing XDEBUG,but still the same problem.Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
zend_extension = /usr/lib/php5/20090626/xdebug.so
xdebug.remote_port = 9001
xdebug.remote_enable=On
xdebug.remote_host="localhost"
```

You PHP.ini should have the above. Just ensure that you give the correct path to xdebug.so